# Time reversal for non-relativistic EM force equation vs relativistic EM force equation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, time-reversal-symmetry

When we reverse time $t\rightarrow -t$ in the non-relativistic equation $m\ddot{\vec{x}} = q\vec{E}$, we find that it stays exactly the same on both sides. However, reversing time $\tau\rightarrow-\tau$ in the relativistic equation $m\frac{d^{2}x^{\mu}}{d\tau^{2}} = qF^{\mu}\,_{\nu}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}$, it seems that we pick up a minus sign on the right-hand side.

Now the issue is that the non-relativistic equation has to be a low velocity limit of the relativistic one, but this seems to naively contradict this. Is there a simple explanation why there is no contradiction here?

Comment: In low velocity limit the 4-velocity is dominated by the time evolution, and both numerator and denominator gets the sign flip, so in the end it gives the same result as the non-relativistic approximation.

Comment: I also wanted to add a small comment. Under time reversal, the field strength tensor should also change by the requirement that Maxwell's equation's remain invariant under time reversal. I believe this would solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that you wrote down the wrong equation for the non-relativistic case. It should be $$\vec F = q (\vec E + \vec v \times \vec B)$$ This has the same dependence on $\vec v \approx \frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}$ as the relativistic case.

So the more interesting question is how both the classical and relativistic expressions become invariant under time reversal. The key is that $\vec B$ also reverses under time reversal. And similarly for $F^\mu{}_\nu$ where the appropriate components also change sign under a time reversal.